# JS: Nested loops to get diagonal rows and columns?

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, nested-loops

I'm a bit confused by my attempt to get a diagonal array from nested loops.

Imagine that there's a chessboard that's 8 by 8 squares and there is a queen in one of those squares. I can compute the queen's possible moves up, right, down, and left perfectly, but I'm stuck on the diagonal moves.

Suppose that the queen is on [4, 4] ([row, column]). I wrote this code to generate/loop through the possible diagonal moves, for example, down left.

The `r_q` is the queen's position on the row of the chessboard (from bottom to up) while the `c_q` is the queen's position on the column of the chessboard (from left to right).

```js
let dlArr = [];
let attackCount = 0;
let r_q = 4, c_q = 4;

for(let dl = r_q - 1; dl > 0; dl--) {
  for(let ld = c_q - 1; ld > 0; ld--) {
    dlArr.push([dl, ld]);
    attackCount++;
  }
}

console.log(dlArr);
```

I got back the array for `dlArr`

```
[ [ 3, 3 ], [ 3, 2 ], [ 3, 1 ], [ 2, 3 ], [ 2, 2 ], [ 2, 1 ], [ 1, 3 ], [ 1, 2 ], [ 1, 1 ] ]
```

instead of what it should be

```
[ [ 3, 3 ], [ 2, 2 ], [ 1, 1 ] ]
```

What did I do wrong in this nested loops I wrote?

All I can see is that it loops through the first loop before going to the second loop....

Comment: The problem is your nested loops. You want both the x and y coordinates to be incremented or decremented at the same time. The nested loops at the minute are decrementing the inner loop through all its values, before decrementing the outer loop. It's essentially walking the table bottom to top, then moving to the next column to the left, then bottom to top again, and repeat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your undesired output is returning every permutation of the correct squares because you nested two `for` loops. Instead, just use a single for loop that decrements each coordinate. This should give you all the squares diagonally Southwest of the Queen:

```js
let dlArr = [];
let attackCount = 0;

let r_q = 4;
let c_q = 4;

let dl = (r_q - 1);
let ld = (c_q - 1);

while (dl > 0 && ld > 0) {
    dlArr.push([dl, ld]);
    attackCount++;
    dl--;
    ld--;
}

console.log(dlArr);
```

`dl` doesn't need to be equivalent to `ld`. There are many positions where this is not the case.

---

Edit:  I thought this shorthand version was funny:

```js
let dlArr = [];
let attackCount = 0;

let r_q = 4;
let c_q = 4;

let dl = r_q; // no need for (r_q - 1)
let ld = c_q; // ditto

while ( (--dl && --ld) > 0 ) {
    dlArr.push([dl, ld]);
    attackCount++;
}

console.log(dlArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the same `slope` is between 2 dots:

```
if(r_q-c_q === dl-ld)
```

So:

```
[4,4],[3,3] 4-4 === 3-3
[4,4],[3,2] 4-4 !== 3-2
```

```js
let dlArr = [];
let attackCount = 0;
let r_q = 4, c_q = 4;

for(let dl = r_q - 1; dl > 0; dl--) {
  for(let ld = c_q - 1; ld > 0; ld--) {
    if(r_q-c_q === dl-ld){
      dlArr.push([dl, ld]);
      attackCount++;
    }
  }
}

console.log(dlArr);
```